# How to assign values to an array of object with same key names

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
 let personNames = [ { firstName: 'Ben' }, {firstName : 'Bob' } ];
 let details=  { city: 'Dublin' , Country: 'Ireland' } ;
 let nameList = [];
 let nameObj = {};
 for(let name of personNames){
   nameObj = details;
   nameObj['f_name'] = name.firstName;
   nameList.push(nameObj);
 }
```

expected output :

```
[ {fname:'Ben', city: 'Dublin' , Country: 'Ireland'}, {fname:'Bob',city: 
'Dublin' , Country: 'Ireland'}]
```

what I'm getting is:

`[ {fname:'Ben', city: 'Dublin' , Country: 'Ireland'}, {fname:'Ben', city: 'Dublin' , Country: 'Ireland'}}]`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Move `let nameObj = {};` inside the loop.](https://jsfiddle.net/uxeqjp21/)

Comment: you are using the same `nameObj` reference.. declare inside your for loop

Comment: @Andy Thanks, it works

Comment: `let nameList = personNames.map(person => ({ fName: person.firstName }))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you doing here is pushing into the array the same reference. You could create each time the nameObj into the for loop in order to have references to different objects in your array.

```
 let personNames = [ { firstName: 'Ben' }, {firstName : 'Bob' } ];
 let nameList = [];
 for(let name of personNames){
   let nameObj = {};
   nameObj['f_name'] = name.firstName;
   nameList.push(nameObj);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using [Array.map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) method, which is ES6

```js
const personNames = [{
  firstName: 'Ben',
}, {
  firstName : 'Bob',
}];

const nameList = personNames.map(x => ({
  f_name: x.firstName,
}));
 
 
console.log(nameList);
```

---

We are looping through `personNames`, and for each element in it, we are creating a new object which contains a key named `f_name`.

Answer (score 0):

nameObj should be inside the for loop